# How to remove some pull requests in between and keep others

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-pull

I am trying to remove some changes pulled from a remote repository to a local server. For instance remove `HEAD@{2}`  and `HEAD@{4}` when I have a total of 7 pull request. How can this be achieved?

Comment: `git pull` is a git command. Do you mean a git *commit*? Remove it from where? Explain clearly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry. I have edited the question.